# HiveAccessControlException Permission denied. [On pyhs2]

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to access data through pyhs2 by writing a select query.

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism="PLAIN",
               user='hue',
               password='',
               database='default') as conn:

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    print cur.getDatabases()

    cur.execute("select * from orders")
    print cur.getSchema()

    for i in cur.fetch():
        print i
```

This gives me an error:

> pyhs2.error.Pyhs2Exception: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied. Principal [name=hue, type=USER] does not have following privileges on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=default.orders] : [SELECT]'

Few available answers suggested using:

```
 grant SELECT on table orders to user hue
```

This again gives me an error:

> yhs2.error.Pyhs2Exception: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Permission denied. Principal [name=hue, type=USER] does not have following privileges on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=default.orders] : [SELECT with grant]'

Answer (score 0):

Before granting privileges ensure you have admin role:

```
show current roles;
```

Probably the user has only **public** role which is not enough. You can set admin role by command:

```
set role admin;
```

See Apache Hive wiki:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization

```
For Hive 0.14 and Newer
Set the following in hive-site.xml:
hive.users.in.admin.role to the list of comma-separated users who need to be added to admin role. Note that a user who belongs to the admin role needs to run the "set role" command before getting the privileges of the admin role, as this role is not in current roles by default.
```